# import numpy could not be resolved message error; ipynb in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ipynb

I opened two ipynb files in vscode, and one is showing error messages.

[image]

this is first file and

[image]

this is second file.

i can run both files without any problems. But those error alrams are really annoying. How can i get rid of it?
those messages are from extension named error lens. Is there any problem with it?

Comment: is the correct python interpreter selercted?

Comment: yeah it even works normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Try the next three methods

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> switch theme
- Add the following settings

  ```json
      "editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true,
      "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
  ```
- Add the package path with the following settings

  ```json
      "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
          "input/lib/path/here"
      ],
      "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
          "input/lib/path/here"
      ],
  ```